# Send and capture URL parameters between 2 react server applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 different react applications running on two different localhost ports. One on 3001 and the other on 3002. 
For the application on port 3001, I need to send a variable 'parameter' to the application on port 3002 for which I have the following route code:

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/pathName" component = {() => window.location.href=`http://localhost:3002?parameter=${store.getState().reducer.parameter} />
```

The above is used in a Link tag as follows:

```
<Link to={'/pathName'}> Click here to send data </Link>
```

Would there be a way to share the 'parameter' variable between the two apps ?

Comment: You can serve both apps in the same port and use localStorage

Comment: To share data between apps on different ports, I think you have to use a cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: I cannot on the same port as they will be separately deployed later on.
Thanks Haken Lid, I will try that